# O(1) complexity search data structure for 2D coordinate grid JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

**Problem**

I'm trying to implement a data structure to represent a map of tiles in p5.js but in JavaScript I can't make a 2D array of set size which would be ideal for searching in constant time.

Currently it is just a simple 1 dimensional array that stores all tile objects in order from top row to the bottom row. Implementation is shown below.

I would like a solution for grabbing a tile object from a specific coordinate without having to search through each tile until the tile objects x and y match what I'm searching for.

**Here is my implementation of the grid:**

```
this.tiles = [];

for(x = 0; x < this.canvasWidth; x += this.tileWidth) {
  for(y = 0; y < this.canvasHeight; y += this.tileHeight) {
    var tile = new Tile(x, y, this.tileWidth, this.tileHeight)
    this.tiles.push(tile);
  }
}
```

**Methods I've Tried**

I tried to implement it using a dictionary type of structure that mapped a coordinate object to the tile object so I could create a coordinate object when searching but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Concatenate `x` and `y` and use it as the key to an object. E.g. `const tilesByCoord = {};` and in your inner `for`: `tilesByCoord[``x${x}y${y}``] = new Tile(...)` (except with a single tick mark because Markdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of arrays instead, the outer array indexed by `x`, and the inner indexed by `y`, with the inner array's values being the tiles:

```
this.tiles = [];
for(x = 0; x < this.canvasWidth; x += this.tileWidth) {
  const xArr = [];
  for(y = 0; y < this.canvasHeight; y += this.tileHeight) {
    var tile = new Tile(x, y, this.tileWidth, this.tileHeight)
    xArr.push(tile);
  }
  this.tiles.push(xArr);
}
```

Then, for example

```
this.tiles[3][6]
```

will refer to the `Tile` with an `x` of 3 and a `y` of 6.

This depends on `x` and `y` starting at 0, as it is in your question. If they didn't start at 0, consider using a `Map` of `Map`s (if the structure is rectangular), or (if the structure is not rectangular) an object with keys that represent the `x` and `y` coordinates, eg

```
{
  "3_4": <tile correspoding to x of 3, y of 4>
}
```

If the structure is rectangular, you could also keep using an array of arrays, as long as you add the starting `x` and `y` indicies to the lookup first, though that might be a bit harder to read.